# Ubuntu 20.04 really slow start

Tags: boot, 20.04

Fist couple of days of me moving to Ubuntu 20.04 this was flying, and now this is the time I get

```
    systemd-analyze time
    Startup finished in 17.732s (firmware) + 9.357s (loader) + 10.604s (kernel) + 2min 13.861s (userspace) = 2min 51.555s 
    graphical.target reached after 2min 13.331s in userspace
```

and the blame

```
systemd-analyze blame
2min 857ms systemd-udev-settle.service                        
    6.461s NetworkManager-wait-online.service                 
    2.869s plymouth-quit-wait.service                         
    1.379s snap.lxd.activate.service                          
    1.334s snapd.service                                      
    1.078s cloud-init-local.service
```

and this is how it looks in the critical chain

```
systemd-analyze critical-chain systemd-udev-settle.service
The time when unit became active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit took to start is printed after the "+" character.

systemd-udev-settle.service +2min 857ms
└─systemd-udev-trigger.service @421ms +121ms
  └─systemd-udevd-kernel.socket @410ms
    └─system.slice @405ms
      └─-.slice @405ms
```

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You can disable `systemd-udev-settle.service` apparently without problems.

From the [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man8/systemd-udev-settle.service.8.html):

> This service calls **udevadm settle** to wait until all events that have
> been queued by
> udev(7) have been processed. It is a crude way to wait until "all" hardware has been
> discovered. Services may pull in this service and order themselves after it to wait for
> the udev queue to be empty.
>
> **Using this service is not recommended.**  There can be no guarantee that hardware is fully
> discovered at any specific time, because the kernel does hardware detection
> asynchronously, and certain buses and devices take a very long time to become ready, and
> also additional hardware may be plugged in at any time. Instead, services should subscribe
> to udev events and react to any new hardware as it is discovered. Services that, based on
> configuration, expect certain devices to appear, may warn or report failure after a
> timeout. This timeout should be tailored to the hardware type. Waiting for
> systemd-udev-settle.service usually slows boot significantly, because it means waiting for
> all unrelated events too.

You can disable it by entering

```
sudo systemctl disable systemd-udev-settle
```

Comment: tried the command and it doesnt work

sudo systemctl disable systemd- [TAB][TAB] and I get this list:
systemd-networkd.service
systemd-networkd-wait-online.service
systemd-resolved.service
systemd-networkd.socket
systemd-pstore.service

Answer (score 0):

In the end, the workaround
sudo systemctl mask systemd-udev-settle
did the job

```
systemd-analyze time
Startup finished in 21.799s (firmware) + 8.493s (loader) + 18.186s (kernel) + 13.149s (userspace) = 1min 1.628s
```